# Correct, full and unambigous data source of layer in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm currently developing a plugin (python, pyqt4) for QGIS 2.10+. Normal data source which I could use should contain complete path to the loaded layer. For example, my Alaska layer when uploaded normally contains path as:

> /home/user/qgis_dataset/shapefiles/Alaska.shp.

The crucial thing for my plugin is to extract correct data source, which proves to be a problem in certain situations. When layers are uploaded as directory, source looks like:

> /home/user/qgis_dataset/shapefiles|layer_id={num}.

Although I derived a hack to solve this problem there are some cases which still remain problematic. Firstly I tried to use provided source and look for file names that match layer.name(), but what if user changes layer name. Than I must use layer.id() which looks like original_layer_name201709281148. For now I'm using layer.name(), layer.source() and layer.id(), and it would be great if there is some kind of method that returns correct data source

Comment: What do you mean by "data source"? Do you mean it in the OGR sense of having  DSN and a layer? Some OGR data sources don't map to files. What do you want to do if the layer is a WMS or other server-based layer?

Comment: I'm strictly speaking about layers that are loaded from local storage (vector/raster layers) that are loadedas files or folders.